# How do I make a class/div behave like it were floating?

Tags: css, css-float, margin, centering, floating

I have an iframe inside a class in the center of my page.  If you click any of the two radio buttons at the top, the form expands depending on which one you select.  If the form is floated right or left, it will expand when one of these buttons is pushed and the gray area below it (the employer and freelancer text section) will move down on the page.  When I align the form in the center of the page, I can't get it to have the property associated with floating that moves the rest of the page down.  Instead, it simply covers up the gray background with text area.  My site is up at [avidest.com/new](http://avidest.com/new).  How can I make the form stay in the center but behave like it were floating?  Here is my css:

```
.main {width:100%; padding:0; margin:0 auto; min-width: 1020px; overflow: hidden;}
.slider { background: transparent; margin:0 auto; padding:0; height:420px;}  
.slider .gallery { margin:0 auto; width:980px; height:420px; padding:0;} 
.formbox{ width: 48%; padding: 45px 60px 20px 0px; margin-top: 30px;background-color:#ffffff;
          border:1px solid black;opacity:0.91;filter:alpha(opacity=91); /* For IE8 and earlier */
          border-radius: 10px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
.body { background: #bebebe; border-top: 0px solid; border-color: #e3e3e3; } 
.body_main_page { width:470px; float:left; margin:0; padding:15px 10px;}
```

And here is the html:

```
<div class="main>
 <div class="slider">
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="formbox"> form is here </formbox>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="body"> 
    <div class="body_main_page">Freelancer Text is here</div>
    <div class="body_main_page">Employer text is here</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing it in the centre in Safari

Comment: Im not having a problem getting it in the center.  When the form expands, I want it to push the rest of the content down like it would if i had it floated right or left.  Now it simply expands over it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your CSS like this:

```
.main {width:100%; padding:0; margin:0 auto; min-width: 1020px; overflow: hidden;}
.slider { background: transparent; margin:0 auto; padding:0; min-height:420px;}  
.slider .gallery { margin:0 auto; width:980px; min-height:420px; padding:0;} 
.formbox{ width: 48%; padding: 45px 60px 20px 0px; margin-top: 30px;background-color:#ffffff;
      border:1px solid black;opacity:0.91;filter:alpha(opacity=91); /* For IE8 and earlier      */
      border-radius: 10px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
 .body { background: #bebebe; border-top: 0px solid; border-color: #e3e3e3; } 
 .body_main_page { width:470px; float:left; margin:0; padding:15px 10px;}
```

Don't provide a fixed height if you want to have e flexible height...

Comment: Great, worked perfectly.  thanks.  Do you have any idea how to make it so that when after it expands there is still some space between the border of the form and the grey background?

Comment: To the .formbox definition add "margin-bottom: 30px;"

Comment: Great, thanks again.  Im interested for my understanding, why isn't it adding the margin when the form is not expanded?